# Java int error cant be int[]

Tags: java

Hey i get the following error int cant be int[] i dont understand it :I

Error is on 
int[] cijferStudent = new int [7]; and in the while loop. If someone can help me i will appreciate it.

Thanks you for your help :)

```
package oefenopdracht6a;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author eazyman
 */
public class Oefenopdracht6a {

    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int aantalCijfers = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        aantalCijfersGeroepen();
    }

    public static void aantalCijfersGeroepen() {
        System.out.println("Hoeveel cijfers wilt u invoeren?");
        aantalCijfers = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i >= aantalCijfers;) {
            System.out.println("Aantal cijfers moet groter zijn dan 0!");
            aantalCijfersGeroepen();
        }

        int i = 0;
        int[] cijferStudent = new int[7];
        while (i < aantalCijfers) {
            System.out.println("Cijfer student " + i);
            cijferStudent = input.nextInt();
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(cijferStudent);

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you tried to affect `cijferStudent = input.nextInt();` but nextInt return an int and `ciferStudent` is an int[]. I think you mean `ciferStudent[i]`

Comment: `cijferStudent` is an array. You can't asign a value to an array like that. You mean `cijferStudent[i] = input.nextInt();`

Comment: `input.nextInt()` returns a single integer, `cijferStudent` you defined as an array of integers, so they're different types. You may want to assign your input token into a field of `cijferStudent`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cijferStudent = input.nextInt();
```

should be changed to

```
cijferStudent[i] = input.nextInt();
```

The error is because `input.nextInt()` will return an int, but `cijferStudent` is an array of `int`, so you cannot assign an `int`to `int[]`. However, you can assign an `int` to a particular location inside the array (which in this case I am guessing would be the `i`th location).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the missing index, for every negative value the users enters
`aantalCijfersGeroepen` will be called, and coming back on a positive number hence N times the array asked to input. So split asking and handling.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    aantalCijfersGeroepen();
    uitgaveAantalCijfers();
}

public static void aantalCijfersGeroepen() {
    System.out.println("Hoeveel cijfers wilt u invoeren?");
    aantalCijfers = input.nextInt();

    while (aantalCijfers <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Aantal cijfers moet groter zijn dan 0!");
        aantalCijfersGeroepen();
    }
}

public static void uitgaveAantalCijfers() {
    int[] cijferStudent = new int[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < aantalCijfers; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Cijfer student " + i);
        cijferStudent[i] = input.nextInt();
        //System.out.println(" " + cijferStudent[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cijferStudent));
}
```

Also the printing of an array must either be done in a loop too,
or use the handy function `Arrays.toString`.